# implementing generic method from typescript interface

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to use typescript generics combined with inheritance, but I am not able to figure why below code results an error

```
interface One {
    // something here
}

interface Two extends One {
    method<T extends One>(val: T): void;
}

class Three implements Two {
    method(val: Three): void {
        // do something with val
    }
}
```

Any clue why it results an error and how to implement it in right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the interface defines a generic method, the implementation must also be generic

```
class Three implements Two {
    method<T extends One>(val: T): void {
        // do something with val
    }
}
```

If you want the interface to implement a function that takes the current type as an argument, you could use the `this` type:

```
interface Two extends One {
    method(val: this): void;
}

class Three implements Two {
    method(val: this): void {
        // do something with val
    }
}

var a = new Three();
a.method(a); //OK
a.method({}); //Not OK
```

Comment: why a.method({} as Two); is allowed?

Comment: Well, if you start using casts, lots of things that should not be allowed become possible. I think the rules for `{}` are a bit different then for other objects. `a.method({ f: 10 } as Two);` still does not work.

Comment: No, it prevents you from casting not passing this type to a method. If you convert Two into a class you'll be able to pass 'new Two()' which is quite strange because it considers method(val: this): void as equivalents but they are not because this is different in every class type, interesting

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thank you, solves the problem. 
MistyK's usecase is also interesting, something to be aware of :)

Comment: After short investigation it seems that typescript is clever enough to find out that passing Two in this case can't break anything unless you add some fields to "Three"

Comment: Type compatibility is structural so that makes sense